# Playing Music on Roblox locally

Tags: audio, lua, roblox

I'm a tad stuck with local music playing on my Roblox game.

I've got a setup on my game where a script inserts **five sound files** into a **player's GUI**. When a sever is made these sounds do make it to the players gui.

To play the sounds there are parts setup that check for collisions with players and when they detect a player they will start one of the **five sounds** in the **player's GUI**.

*This is what the code in one of the parts looks like:*

```
script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)

if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid') then
    if game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound2.TimePosition < 1 then
        game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound2.Volume = 1
        game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound2:Play()
        game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound1:Stop()
        game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound4:Stop()
        game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound3:Stop()
        game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound5:Stop()
    end
end

end)
```

This script does detect players just fine as I have tested it. The system does work in the Roblox Studio testing area however when a server is launched with it none of the sounds are played.

The server does in fact set the sounds to playing and they appear as playing on the client side from the server side however the client side does not see them as playing and they do not play.

I do have filtering enabled turned on but this shouldn't effect it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering enabled is the reason this doesn't work.

To solve this you can use a **RemoteEvent** located in the **ReplicatedStorage** of your game.

The sounds must be placed in the **StarterGUI** and there should be a localscript with this code:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local event = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("REMOTE EVENT NAME")
script.Parent.Sound2.Playing = true

local function onNewPlayerFired(sound)
    script.Parent.Sound1.Playing = false
    script.Parent.Sound2.Playing = false
    script.Parent.Sound3.Playing = false
    script.Parent.Sound4.Playing = false
    script.Parent.Sound5.Playing = false

    script.Parent[sound].Playing = true

end

event.OnClientEvent:Connect(onNewPlayerFired)
```

and in the part for each sound trigger part there should be this code:

```
local debounce = false

script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if debounce == true then return end
    debounce = true
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid') then
        local plr = game.Players:FindFirstChild(hit.Parent.Name)
        game.ReplicatedStorage.REMOTE EVENT NAME:FireClient(plr,"SOUND NAME")


    end
wait(2)
    debounce = false        

end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is something quite simple. I think it is a function of the SoundService. Correct me if this doesnt work, but i believe this is it

```
soundobj = game.Players[hit.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Sound2

game:GetService('SoundService'):PlayLocalSound(soundobj)
```

see https://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/SoundService/PlayLocalSound for more info

Comment: This is is the way to play the sound but playing SoundService sounds will only work locally and not through the server so it wont work in this case

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that is parenting the sounds to PlayerGui (I think you needed a ScreenGui) and then :Play() them.

Comment: Yes they are only playable in the PlayerGui though localscripts on the client so the ScreenGui would be the way to do it however I would like to use the server to start the songs

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue while making a music player. It ended up being the silliest thing and had everything to do with FE. My player worked in Test Studio, but gave me a whole laundry list of error codes that I was able to fix simply by changing the script to a local script. Literally all the same code worked as it did in studio but client side. It took me a entire day of head scratching and wiki searching to figure out my mistake. FE was initially a nightmare for me, but I have come to love the security it provides my games. :)

Comment: Yeah fair FE does kind of suck. Its a huge change to the system but I understand it more and I'm more confident in developing in FE than not now.